# Searching for similar elements in a list of list

Tags: python

I have a table containing:

```
table = [[1, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE'],[4, 'CRIMSON PEAK', 'MINIONS','SUPERMAN'],[20, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE']]
```

and I'm writing a python function to traverse through the table, look for similarities in the string elements and printing out in the format:

```
Movie: FANTASTIC FOUR, EXOTIC SPACE
UserID: 1,20   #since user 1 and user 20 both watch exactly the same movie
```

I have tried writing:

```
i = 0
while i<len(table)-1:
    g = table[i][1:]
    if g == table[i+1][1:]:
        print(table[i][0],table[i+1][0])
    i+=1
```

but it's not working very well. I'm not that good at using while loops for printing so i'll appreciate some help on this.

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem description. What output do you get?

Comment: "it's not working very well": what does that mean? Can you give an minimal example which includes the expected behavior and the actual behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Loops in Python usually don't use `i` very much. Try this:

```
table = [[1, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE'],[4, 'CRIMSON PEAK', 'MINIONS','SUPERMAN'],[20, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE']]

watcher = {}

for x in table:
    for movie in x[1:]:
        watcher_for_movie = watcher.get(movie, [])
        watcher_for_movie.append(x[0])
        watcher[movie] = watcher_for_movie

print(watcher)
```

Output:

```
{'EXOTIC SPACE': [1, 20], 'CRIMSON PEAK': [4], 'MINIONS': [4], 'SUPERMAN': [4], 'FANTASTIC FOUR': [1, 20]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using `itertool.combinations` and dictionaries.

Using sets, or frozensets for dictionary keys, is the best option as you want the same results whether you look for `(1, 20)` or `(20, 1)`.

```
from itertools import combinations

table = [[1, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE'],
         [4, 'CRIMSON PEAK', 'MINIONS','SUPERMAN'],
         [20, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE']]

d = {k: set(v) for k, *v in table}

common = {frozenset((i, j)): d[i] & d[j] for i, j in \
          combinations(d, 2) if d[i] & d[j]}

# {frozenset({1, 20}): {'EXOTIC SPACE', 'FANTASTIC FOUR'}}
```

It's also trivial to reverse this mapping:

```
common_movies = {frozenset(v): set(k) for k, v in common.items()}

# {frozenset({'EXOTIC SPACE', 'FANTASTIC FOUR'}): {1, 20}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionaries to get users who watched same movies from `table`

```
table = [[1, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE'],[4, 'CRIMSON PEAK', 'MINIONS','SUPERMAN'],[20, 'FANTASTIC FOUR', 'EXOTIC SPACE']]
movie_user_mapping = dict() # Create an empty dictionary

# Iterate over every item in table
for item in table:
     # Loop over the movies i.e excluding the first element
     for movie in item[1:]:
         # Check if movie is present as key in the dictionary, if not create a new key with the movie name and assign it an empty list
         if movie not in movie_user_mapping:
             movie_user_mapping[movie] = []
         # Check if user is already added to the list for the movie, if not add the user
         if item[0] not in movie_user_mapping[movie]:
             movie_user_mapping[movie].append(item[0])

# Print the result
print(movie_user_mapping)
```

Output:

```
{'FANTASTIC FOUR': [1, 20], 'EXOTIC SPACE': [1, 20], 'CRIMSON PEAK': [4], 'MINIONS': [4], 'SUPERMAN': [4]}
```